How to convert .las file format to kitti file format?
I'm trying to apply moving object segmentation techniques to point cloud data. All I have available are .las files, but most frameworks only accept KITTI .bin input files.
From what I've read, the KITTI format is different because it stores the label of each point in the point cloud. I'd like to convert the .las file to an unlabeled .bin file, after which the framework can do its labeling magic.
I've found a single question on this topic, which hasn't got a lot of traction... If anyone could give some insights into this, it would be greatly appreciated. If possible, I'd like to do the conversion in Python, C++ or a shell script.

research who came up with that .las file format (and/or the other format too), and if there is any spec or other description of the format. if you can't find a spec for the format, then research programs that use the format, then look into their source code.
